# Eclipse Scala interpreter (REPL) - proper use and debugging

Tags: debugging, scala, eclipse-plugin, read-eval-print-loop, scala-ide

I would like to know what are best practises of using Eclipse Scala interpreter (Eclipse Scala IDE).

Let's say I have application with breakpoint in it. Is it possible to debug an application in such a way, that I can execute/evaluate expressions inside REPL at the specific breakpoint? If yes how can I achieve it?

Another thing that made me wonder is what's the difference between opening the interpreter as `Run configuration` or opening it trough `Window -> Show view -> Scala interpreter`.

Do you know any other uses cases of Eclipse Scala interpreter that are interesting to know about, like for example `Ctrl+Shift+X` to run selected expression?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe it is an obvious advice, but in addition to merely starting REPL in Scala IDE you can run selected expression in it: just select the expression and press Ctrl+Shift+X (default hotkey).

**Update**
There is a comprehensive [reference](http://scala-ide.org/docs/user/features/scalainterpreter.html) for Scala interpreter (thanks Mirco Dotta).
It is also worth to mention that in near future Scala interpreter is going to be enhanced significantly: integration with Scala [debugger](http://scala-ide.org/docs/helium/features/scaladebugger/index.html) and implementation of a concept known as [worksheet](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000865) are on the way.

Comment: At the moment REPL seems to be not very advanced, but I have high hopes for this one, http://www.assembla.com/spaces/scala-ide/tickets/1000865 
It is accepted for inclusion in Milestone 2 and M2 is scheduled to July.

Comment: [Scala debuger](http://scala-ide.org/docs/helium/features/scaladebugger/index.html) as part of Scala IDE 2.1 will provide some net features... You can find all new features of IDE 2.1 [here](http://scala-ide.org/blog/release-notes-2.1-Milestone-1.html).

Comment: For future reference, here is a link to the [Eclipse Scala Interpreter documentation](http://scala-ide.org/docs/user/features/scalainterpreter.html). @PrimosK is right, and we want to experiment if we can attach a REPL to the debugger so that you can evaluate expression at breakpoints.